# When does this patent expire?

Tags: patent-lifetime

I thought patents expired a max of 15 years after publication date. Why does it seem like this patent still has until US Copyright Law expires (75 years)?

In reference to the patent: [US2717437](https://www.google.com/patents/US2717437)

Comment: How does it seem like that?

Comment: There's rumors going around that Velcro is suing Resellers on eBay that are selling clothing items with Velcro on them. Since I've recently acquired fishing Shirts made by Columbia that use Velcro, it is a concern to me.

Comment: Such rumor is almost certainly false, but you can ask for clarification in the proper forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A US patent issued in 1955 had an expiration of 17 years after issuance.  US copyright expiration has nothing to do with patent expiration.

Longer answer: The  17-year rule was changed for utility patent applications filed after June 8, 1995, at which point the patent term became "20 years after filing". More variations and details can be found at 35 USC § 154 and MPEP § 2701.

Comment: This answer would be even better if you explained how the rules changed in 1995.

Comment: Thanks, but I felt the specific rules were beyond the scope necessary to answer the question actually being asked. I'm new here, so maybe I should attempt to be succinct rather than dangerously garrulous?

Comment: In truth, this question (except for the specific patent number) has been asked and answered multiple times of this site and should be marked as a duplicate. That said, one has to remember that others may see this answer and assume that 17 years from grant date is the answer for all patents. That's why it is useful to mention the fact that the rules changed in 1995.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad that they cannot sue me for Patent Infringement just because I'm a Reseller on eBay (there's rumors going around about this for clothing items with Velcro on them). I'll have to look elsewhere in regards to Copyright Infringement, as I know it's against the rules of this website to ask about those questions.

Comment: Unclear how copyright or even trademark might apply to your question.

Comment: @Anthonyk747 I don't think Copyright applies, but trademarks might. Velcro probably is a trademark, so they might be able to restrict reselling if their trademark appears on the clothes. Maybe.